# Strange behaviour for arrows between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to write a few macros for drawing MPM diagrams. This is the MWE I can provide :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\noeud[6]{%
  % #1 : Task name, #2 : task duration, #3 : sooner start time,
  % #4 : later start time, #5 : total margin, #6 : free margin
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick] ++(-0.8,0) -- (0.8,0);
    \draw[black,thick] ++(0,-0.6) -- (0,0.6);
    \draw[black,thick] ++(-0.8,-0.6) rectangle ++(1.6,1.8);
    \draw[black,thick] ++(-0.8,0.6) rectangle ++(1.6,0);
    \draw[black] ++(0,0.9) node{#1\ (#2)};
    \draw[blue] ++(-0.4,0.3) node{#3};
    \draw[green!75!black] ++(0.4,0.3) node{#4};
    \draw[green!75!black] ++(-0.4,-0.3) node{#5};
    \draw[violet] ++(0.4,-0.3) node{#6};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand\noeudcritique[6]{%
  % #1 : Task name, #2 : task duration, #3 : sooner start time,
  % #4 : later start time, #5 : total margin, #6 : free margin
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick] ++(-0.8,0) -- (0.8,0);
    \draw[black,thick] ++(0,-0.6) -- (0,0.6);
    \draw[red,thick] ++(-0.8,-0.6) rectangle ++(1.6,1.8);
    \draw[black,thick] ++(-0.8,0.6) rectangle ++(1.6,0);
    \draw[black] ++(0,0.9) node{#1\ (#2)};
    \draw[blue] ++(-0.4,0.3) node{#3};
    \draw[green!75!black] ++(0.4,0.3) node{#4};
    \draw[green!75!black] ++(-0.4,-0.3) node{#5};
    \draw[violet] ++(0.4,-0.3) node{#6};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\fleche}[5]{%
  % #1 : starting node, #2 : ending node,
  % #3 : sooner start time forward, #4 : sooner start time backward,
  % #5 : later start time
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,black,-Latex] (#1) node[near start,above,blue]{#4}
    node[near start,below,green!75!black]{#5}
    -- (#2) %node[near end,above,black]{#3};
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\flechecritique}[5]{%
  % #1 : starting node, #2 : ending node,
  % #3 : sooner start time forward, #4 : sooner start time backward,
  % #5 : later start time
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,red,-Latex] (#1) node[near start,above,blue]{#4}
    node[near start,below,green!75!black]{#5}
    -- (#2) node[near end,above,black]{#3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep = 0}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {\noeudcritique{A}{2}{0}{0}{0}{0}};
    \node (B) at (3,2) {\noeud{B}{5}{2}{6}{4}{2}};
    \node (C) at (3,-2) {\noeudcritique{C}{7}{2}{2}{0}{0}};
    % \draw[thick,black,-Latex] (A) node[near start,above,blue]{#4}
    % node[near start,below,green!75!black]{#5}  -- (B) node[near
    % end,above,black]{#3};
    \fleche{A}{B}{2}{4}{5};
    \flechecritique{A}{C}{2}{2}{2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you will note the arrows are not correctly placed.

[image]

Where did I go wrong ?

I'd like results like this :

[image]

or this :

[image]

The idea being that blue labels are drawn during the forward update of nodes (they are minimum starting dates of tasks), the green (and violet in my example) labels during the backward process of the nodes (they are maximum ending dates).

Those pictures where realized by hand typesetting, but they are quite long to type, I'd like to automate things a little.

Thanks for any help.

\bye

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed what the correct placement was supposed to be. Also, you are nesting `tikzpicture`, which is highly _not_ recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided MWE has nested `tikzpicture`s, which does not work well in general. However, the nodes are tables, so you can also use the `tabular` environment for this.

Another issue was the position of the arrow nodes in the code. Nodes should be specified after the arrow, i.e., `(a) --(b) [nodes here]`. This corrects the positioning of the arrow labels.

The code could be simplified a bit further by calling the `\noeud` command from the `\noeudcritique` command with an extra argument for the line colors (otherwise the two commands are identical).

The code for the tables becomes a bit messy with the exact configuration of line colors, line thickness and cell padding for the table, which requires a combination of `\arraystretch`, `\tabcolsep`, `\arrayrulewidth`, `\arrayrulecolor`, and some exotic tabular column specifications using colored `\vrule`s. Other than that it is relatively straightforward :)

In the MWE below the position of the start and end point of the arrows on the border of the tables is specified, because otherwise the arrows start and end at the center of the node (in the middle of the table). This can be done either with positions such as `north west`, `south` etc., or with degrees (from 0 to 360, turning left (counter-clockwise), with 0/360 at the middle right (i.e., east). Furthermore I adjusted the `above` and `below` positions slightly so the numbers do not overlap the arrow.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\noeud}[7][black]{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}%
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}%
\arrayrulecolor{#1}%
\begin{tabular}{|c!{\color{black}\vrule}c|}
\hline
\arrayrulecolor{black}%
\multicolumn{2}{!{\color{#1}\vrule width 1pt}c!{\color{#1}\vrule width 1pt}}{#2 (#3)}\\
\hline
\textcolor{blue}{#4} & \textcolor{green}{#5}\\
\hline
\textcolor{green}{#6} & \textcolor{violet}{#7}\\
\arrayrulecolor{#1}%
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\noeudcritique[6]{%
\noeud[red]{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
}

\newcommand{\fleche}[5]{%
  % #1 : starting node, #2 : ending node,
  % #3 : sooner start time forward, #4 : sooner start time backward,
  % #5 : later start time
  \draw[thick,black,-Latex] (#1) -- (#2) node[near start,above=3pt,blue]{#4}
    node[near start,below=3pt,green!75!black]{#5} node[near end,above=4pt,black]{#3}
    ;
}

\newcommand{\flechecritique}[5]{%
  % #1 : starting node, #2 : ending node,
  % #3 : sooner start time forward, #4 : sooner start time backward,
  % #5 : later start time
  \draw[thick,red,-Latex] (#1) -- (#2) node[near start,above=3pt,blue]{#4}
    node[near start,below=3pt,green!75!black]{#5} node[near end,above=4pt,black]{#3}
    ;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep = 0}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {\noeudcritique{A}{2}{0}{0}{0}{0}};
    \node (B) at (3,2) {\noeud{B}{5}{2}{6}{4}{2}};
    \node (C) at (3,-2) {\noeudcritique{C}{7}{2}{2}{0}{0}};
    \fleche{A.north east}{B.210}{2}{4}{5}
    \flechecritique{A.330}{C.160}{2}{2}{2}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you. I'll learn a lot from your code :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you like to draw. I guess that something similar to the following image:

[image]

**Edit:**
Now is reproduced the first image ...

Above image is drawn with

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159mm]{standalone}  % :-)
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning}
\newcommand\matrixgrid[1]{
    \draw   (#1-1-1.south west) -- (#1-1-2.south east)
            (#1-2-1.south west) -- (#1-2-2.south east)
            (#1-1-1.south east) -- (#1-3-1.south east);
                        }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
M/.style = {matrix of nodes,
            nodes in empty cells,
            nodes = {thin,minimum width=2em, minimum height=3ex, anchor=center},
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            %
            row 2 column 1/.style={text=blue},
            row 2 column 2/.style={text=teal},
            row 3 column 1/.style={text=teal},
            row 2 column 1/.style={text=purple},
            %
            inner sep=0pt, draw=#1, thick},
       arr/.style = {draw, semithick, - Stealth},
       lbl/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, text=#1, inner sep=2pt, sloped}
                    ]
\matrix (m1) [M=red]
{
    &       \\
0   &    0  \\
0   &    0  \\
};
\node[fit=(m1-1-1) (m1-1-2), label=center:{$A(1)$}] {};
\matrixgrid{m1};
%
\matrix (m2) [M=black, above right=of m1]
{
    &       \\
2   &    6  \\
4   &    2  \\
};   
\node[fit=(m2-1-1) (m2-1-2), label=center:{$A(1)$}] {};
\matrixgrid{m2};
%
%
\matrix (m2) [M=black, above right=of m1]
{
    &       \\
2   &    6  \\
4   &    2  \\
};   
\node[fit=(m2-1-1) (m2-1-2), label=center:{$A(1)$}] {};
\matrixgrid{m2};
%
\matrix (m3) [M=black,below right=of m1]
{
    &       \\
2   &    2  \\
0   &    0  \\
};
\node[fit=(m3-1-1) (m3-1-2), label=center:{$A(1)$}] {};
\matrixgrid{m3};
%
\draw[arr]  (m1) -- node [lbl=blue,above] {4}
                    node [lbl=green, near start, below] {5}
                    node [lbl=black, near end, above]  {2} (m2-3-1.west);
\draw[arr]  (m1) -- node [lbl=green,below] {2}
                    node [lbl=blue, near start, above] {5}
                    node [lbl=black, near end, above]  {2} (m3-1-1.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which can further make shorter with defining new command for drawing lines in matrices.

Whether the above solution is what you after?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I clarified my expectations for the final graph by editing my initial post. I'll study your code, I'm sure I'll learn a lot from it :-)